# PostgreSQL triggers in rails app? How to execute "createlang plpgsql database_name"?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, triggers

If I am going to use postgres triggers in a rails app, I can use execute { create trigger } for creating a trigger in migration file. But where am I supposed to write these lines? `createlang plpgsql databasename;`

Answer (score 1):

Use the SQL *execute("CREATE LANGUAGE plpgsql")* instead, and put this statement in your standard migration.